# How to decrease the size of the <tabview> buttons when are orientation:"left", using PrimeFaces

Tags: button, primefaces, size, tabview

```
<p:tabView orientation="left" dynamic="false" cache="false" style="font-size: 70% !important; **wight:300px**; border: none;">
    <p:tab title="mainBoard" id="mainboard" style="font-size: 70% !important; width:200px">
        <p:scrollPanel style="width:800px;height: 600px;border: none;"  mode="native">
            <ui:include src="/mainboard.xhtml" />
        </p:scrollPanel>
    </p:tab>

    <p:tab title="secBoard" id="secboard" style="font-size: 70% !important; width:200px">
        <p:scrollPanel style="width:800px;height: 600px;border: none;"  mode="native">
            <ui:include src="/secboard.xhtml" />
        </p:scrollPanel>
    </p:tab>
</p:tabView>
```

*** **wight:300px from tabview **  ***  also from  - it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

You will probably need to include a separate CSS file and set the `.ui-tabs-left > .ui-tabs-nav` width. I tested the code below with various sizes, and it seems to work.

```
.ui-tabs-left > .ui-tabs-nav {
    width:300px !important;
    }
```

You may run into trouble with the content panel being forced below the tabs. I used the following code to prevent that from happening on a project I created a while back.

```
.ui-tabs-left > .ui-tabs-panels {
    height:100% !important;
    float:right !important;
    width:89% !important;
    }

.ui-tabs-left > .ui-tabs-nav {
    float:left !important;
    width:10% !important;
    height:100% !important;
    }
```